# How to wait for callback function in angular6+ unit test (Jasmine+karma)

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, angular6, karma-jasmine

---

**Update:**

This seems issue with FileReader. Found this [link](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31702)

Can anyone suggest how can I write unit test for FileReader related thing

---

I have instance where I have callback inside observable subscribe callback.

Component.ts

```
 public ngOnInit(): void {
 this.subscriptions.push(this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
 this.service.getAttachment()
      .subscribe(response => {
          this.convertBlobToBase46String(response.contentBytes, 
          async (data) => {
              this.fileData = data;
          });
        this.isAttachmentLoadingCompleted = true;
      }, error => {
        this.isAttachmentLoadingCompleted = true;
        this.loggingServie.logError(error, 'Error occurred while fetching attachment.');
      });
 }));
}

 private convertBlobToBase46String(resp, callback) {
         const reader = new FileReader();
         reader.onload = function () {
                        callback(reader.result);
                        };
         reader.readAsDataURL(resp);
    }

public isAttachmentVisible(): boolean {
       if (this.fileData != null && this.isAttachmentLoadingCompleted) {
           return true;
         }

      return false;
}
```

component.spec.ts

```
it('should hide attachment if attachment is not visible', fakeAsync(() => {
  let content = "Hello World";
  let data = new Blob([content], { type: 'text/plain' });
  let arrayOfBlob = new Array<Blob>();
  arrayOfBlob.push(data);
  let file = new File(arrayOfBlob, "Mock.svc");

  spyOn(service, 'getAttachment').and
    .returnValue(Observable.of({ mimeType: 'text/plain', contentBytes: file }));

  component.ngOnInit();
  fixture.detectChanges();
  tick(40);

  const returnValue = component.isAttachmentVisible();

  expect(returnValue).toBe(true);
  }));
```

Here `fileData` is set inside callback function and it is used in `isAttachmentVisible()` method so it should wait for callback to complete. But it doesn't wait for it, even though I increased tick value, it calls `isAttachmentVisible()` before seting `fileData`

Answer (score 1):

Change your `ngOnInit` to as follows, having nested `subscribes` is an anti-pattern.

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
  this.subscriptions.push(
    this.route.paramMap.pipe(
     switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.service.getAttachment()),
   ).subscribe(response => {
      // not sure why the callback is marked as async, nothing async about this
      this.convertBlobToBase465String(response.contentBytes, async data => {
        this.fileData = data;
        // see the bottom log when you run your test
        console.log(this.fileData);
      });
      this.isAttachmentLoadingCompleted = true;
   }, error => {
      this.isAttachmentLoadingCompleted = true;
      this.loggingService.logError(error, 'Error occured while fetching attachment.');
    });
  );
}

public isAttachmentVisible(): boolean {
       if (this.fileData != null && this.isAttachmentLoadingCompleted) {
           console.log('returing true for isAttachmentVisible');
           return true;
         }

      return false;
}
```

Then change your test to be:

```
it('should hide scanned image if image is not visible', async(done) => {
  let content = "Hello World";
  let data = new Blob([content], { type: 'text/plain' });
  let arrayOfBlob = new Array<Blob>();
  arrayOfBlob.push(data);
  let file = new File(arrayOfBlob, "Mock.svc");

  spyOn(service, 'getAttachment').and
    .returnValue(Observable.of({ mimeType: 'text/plain', contentBytes: file }));

  component.ngOnInit();
  fixture.detectChanges();
  // fixture.whenStable() waits for promises to complete, maybe you need two of these
  await fixture.whenStable();
  // await fixture.whenStable();
  console.log('fileData: ', component.fileData);
  console.log('isAttachmentLoadingCompleted: ', component.isAttachmentLoadingCompleted);
  // make sure above logs to not null and true, make them public just to see the log then
  // you can set them back to private if you would like.
  const returnValue = component.isAttachmentVisible();

  expect(returnValue).toBe(true);
  done();
});
```

Comment: I will try this. we have multiple nested subscribe in our code.

Answer (score 0):

Your test may work as expected if you replace [`tick()`](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/tick) by [`flush()`](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/flush) since the `callback` is nested inside a `subscribe()` call.

> `flush` simulates the asynchronous passage of time for the timers in the
>   `fakeAsync` zone by draining the macrotask queue until it is empty.

Comment: I tried using flush as well. Then also it doesn't wait for callBack

Comment: Is `this.service.getAttachment()...` located inside the method `ngOnInit`?

Comment: Actually that is written in this.route.paramMap.subscribe(). And this subscription is written in ngOnInit()

Comment: You somehow need to feed the `Observable<ParamMap>` in order to have the subscription triggered.

Comment: That is getting triggered. Callback is getting called. but the problem is after ngOnInit it directly check for assert (Expect) statement. I want it to wait for callback to complete.